# how to plot multiplot (two columns plots) per page in a single pdf?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot and `ggplot.multiplot` function to plot multiplots (2 columns plots) per page but I couldnt make it. please help

I have a list of ggplots in variable plot_list and using function `ggplot2.multiplot` to plot 2 plot per page. But it plot all figures in one page that messed up. I want two plot per page in single figure.

```
>plot_list ## ggplot saved in a list though i have long list to plot
[[1]]

[[2]]

[[3]]

[[4]]
```

In both case i tried but all four plots plotted in same page:

```
library(easyGgplot2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot2.multiplot(plotlist = plot_list, cols=2)
ggplot2.multiplot(plotlist = plot_list)
```

However its work as:

```
ggplot2.multiplot(plot_list[[1]],plot_list[[2]],cols=2)
ggplot2.multiplot(plot_list[[3]],plot_list[[4]],cols=2)
```

But i have long list of figures to generate in a single pdf !!

I also i have tried `library("cowplot")` but got error while using list of figures.

```
plot_grid(plot_list, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

Error in ggplot_to_gtable(x) : 
  Argument needs to be of class "ggplot" or "gtable"
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you open to using par(mfrow=c(2,2)) for the four plots you want to plot?

Also, some grid.arrange function will do the trick here too probably.

Comment: See this link for what I am talking about.

http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html

Comment: Where did you get that `ggplot.multiplot` function? Furthermore: It is always good to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's `gridExtra::marrangeGrob`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

 pl <- replicate(5, ggplot(), simplify=FALSE)
 ml <- marrangeGrob(pl, nrow=1, ncol=2)
 ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for your cowplot problem, there is an argument plotlist in the plot_grid function (https://rdrr.io/cran/cowplot/man/plot_grid.html):

`plot_grid(plotlist=plot_list)`

should work